# How to save/export all the settings of IntelliJ IDEA?

Tags: intellij-idea

I would like to reinstall my operating system and keep the **IntelliJ IDEA** settings (like colors, indents, inspections, etc.). Is there a way to save my settings to keep them during operating system reinstalling?

Comment: You can backup [config/plugin folders](http://intellij-support.jetbrains.com/entries/23358108) as exporting settings will not affect plugins.

Comment: @CrazyCoder So to summarize, to fully backup IDEA, one needs to manually backup the files in `~/.IntellijIdea14`, export settings per @Vic below, manually backup run configurations per @Matt below, and manually backup a handful of other files in the project `.idea` file and possibly some `.iml` files?

Comment: @jordanpg Did you ever find the answer to your question above? It sure seems to be messy to do it that way.

Comment: @stepanian no. this backup issue is probably the biggest complaint I have about IDEA.  I live in fear of a windows crash while IDEA is in the middle of re-indexing.

Comment: @jordanpg haha! me too.

Comment: If the aim is to export & import settings around devices, check the sync features of jetbrains IDEs. https://stackoverflow.com/a/51019780/2545439

Comment: Fyi, in Intellij you can use `ctrl+shift+a` to search for things you don't know. In this case you would type "export settings" and find it immediately. I learned a lot of features this way.

Answer (score 63, accepted):

**2020.01 version and above**

<kbd>File</kbd> → <kbd>Manage IDE Settings</kbd> → <kbd>Export settings</kbd>

**Below 2020.01**

<kbd>File</kbd> → <kbd>Export Settings</kbd>.

You can disable the "Settings repository" under File --> Settings --> Plugins but this doesn't seem to make a blind bit of difference to your ability to export settings "manually".

In the later versions it seems like you should go with either configuring a settings repository or using IDE Settings Sync plugin. More information [here](https://www.jetbrains.com/help/idea/sharing-your-ide-settings.html):

> IntelliJ IDEA lets you share your settings between different instances
> of your IDE. This helps you recreate a comfy working environment if
> you are working from different computers and spare the annoyance of
> things looking or behaving differently from what you are used to.
>
> You can share your settings in one of the following ways:
>
> By configuring a settings repository. This allows you to sync any
> configurable components (except for the list of enabled and disabled
> plugins), but requires setting up a Git repository with the settings
> you want to share. This option is useful if you want to implement the
> same settings among your team-members.
>
> By using the IDE Settings Sync plugin. It utilizes the JetBrains
> server, so no additional configuration is required. Synced settings
> are linked to your JetBrains Account, so they will not be available to
> other users. The settings you can sync include: IDE themes, keymaps,
> color schemes, system settings, UI settings, menus and toolbars
> settings, project view settings, editor settings, code completion
> settings, parameter name hints, live templates, code styles, and the
> list of enabled and disabled plugins.

Comment: On IntelliJ IDEA on Mac OS High Sierra, File -> Export Settings option isn't present.

Comment: @user674669 You're right, thanks for pointing it out! I've edited the answer

Comment: to @user674669 File → "Export Settings..." option - IF not present then you have enabled "Settings Sync" ( https://www.jetbrains.com/help/idea/sharing-your-ide-settings.html#IDE_settings_sync ) To enable "Export Settings" in the bottom-right corner of the IntelliJ IDEA window, click the gear icon settings sync icon and select disable sync.

Comment: The comment by Lukas is now (2020.01 version) out-of-date. You have to go File --> Manage IDE Settings --> Export settings.  You can disable the "Settings repository" under File --> Settings --> Plugins but this doesn't seem to make a blind bit of difference to your ability to export settings "manually".

Comment: Can you export Intellij settings to other JetBrains products like Pycharm, Clion ect.?

Comment: In newer versions it seems that `IDE Settings Sync` plugin is enabled by default and settings are synced with your `Jetbrains Account`. Haven't tested it yet. This doesn't seem to affect `templates` though.

Comment: Does this way work across different operating systems?

Answer (score 9):

All your settings are in a configuration directory that depends on you OS. You can just take the entire directory. Mine is in my home directory `C:\Users\Me\.IntelliJIdea12` Just placing that in the same location on your new os before you install IntelliJ should work. It is what I do myself.

Answer (score 9):

> File --> Export Settings...

AND don't forget to backup your `Run Configurations`!
Go to where your workspace is located, there is a .idea folder.
(i.e:  `/Users/matthew/codebase/.idea`)

Copy the `runConfigurations` folder and paste in your new workspace.
That's it!

Comment: It depends on whether you want to export local configuration or shared configuration: User configuration is in `workspace.xml` file under `.idea`, shared configuration under `runConfigurations`

Comment: In order to see the `runConfigurations` folder inside your `.idea` folder, you need to enable the "Store as a project file" check in Run -> Edit Configurations...

Answer (score 7):

For the new IntelliJ IDEA version `2020.03` version:
<kbd>File</kbd> → <kbd>Manage IDE Settings</kbd> → <kbd>Export Settings...</kbd>

[image]

Answer (score 2):

Personally, I have found the `Export Settings` method to be most effective for transporting my settings between multi-platform dev environments (using an external service such as Google Drive to store them). Sure it's not as simple as using the 'Settings Sync' plugin, but it allows you to experiment with a wider variety of individual configurations (assuming you name your various configurations descriptively).

> File --> Export Settings

With this method there is also the additional burden of transferring your `runConfigurations` data, as described in a previous answer. However, at the cost of increased complexity is increased freedom for experimentation.

However, if you only plan on using one configuration, I'd recommend the Sync Settings plugin. You can read more about its usage here:

https://www.jetbrains.com/help/idea/sharing-your-ide-settings.html

Answer (score 1):

**IntelliJ IDEA 2021.2.2**

You can migrate settings between Windows installations without using the *Import/Export Settings* feature, by copying files from the JetBrains\IntelliJIdea* folder underneath the user's profile AppData\Roaming directory.

IntelliJ IDEA 2021.2.2 saves its configuration in `%USERPROFILE%\JetBrains\IntelliJIdea2021.2`.  Typically `%USERPROFILE%` is `C:\Users\<USERNAME>`, where <USERNAME> is your Windows username.

To allow for everything else to update, I only copied the options, consoles, codestyles, and scratches directories.

Thus, you're able to recover your (2021.2.2) IDE settings from an inactive/not-booted Windows installation, by restoring these directories to your new Windows installation:

```
C:\Users\<USERNAME>\AppData\Roaming\JetBrains\IntelliJIdea2021.2\options
C:\Users\<USERNAME>\AppData\Roaming\JetBrains\IntelliJIdea2021.2\scratches
C:\Users\<USERNAME>\AppData\Roaming\JetBrains\IntelliJIdea2021.2\consoles
C:\Users\<USERNAME>\AppData\Roaming\JetBrains\IntelliJIdea2021.2\codestyles
```

Answer (score 0):

There is anouther underground method. Back up all the settings folders.
Here is a [tutorial](https://practical-start.blogspot.com.eg/2016/12/changing-android-studio-settings.html) based on android studio but exactly applicable to intellij idea

Answer (score 0):

`Ctrl` + `Shift` + `A`

Type: `export settings`

[image: Actions dialog]

[image: Export settings dialog]

```
IntelliJ IDEA 2022.3.2 (Community Edition)
Build #IC-223.8617.56, built on January 26, 2023
```