# Propagate IntelliJ IDEA project settings

Tags: eclipse, intellij-idea

Is there any tool or plugin for intellij that let you propagate project settings (code formatting etc) across your team ?, something like [Eclipse Workspace Mechanic](https://marketplace.eclipse.org/content/workspace-mechanic) for eclipse

Comment: Possible duplicate of [How to save/export all the settings of IntelliJ IDEA?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/15863256/how-to-save-export-all-the-settings-of-intellij-idea)

Answer (score 1):

Yes, you can select `File` -> `Export Settings...` and there you can find all properties you can export.

After that you give that `settings.jar` to all your team members, and all they need to do is `File` -> `Import settings...` and select all properties they want to be imported.

You can find more information [here](https://www.jetbrains.com/help/idea/2016.3/exporting-and-importing-settings.html).

If you want it to be done automatically, you can look at `Settings repository` plugin (Preferences -> Plugins). It's description you can find [here](https://github.com/develar/settings-repository).

Comment: Yes but i think that workspace mechanic is more flexible because i can specify which settings should be shared by team, not all ...

Answer (score 1):

You don't need to export/import IDE settings for that. Using [Settings Repository](https://www.jetbrains.com/help/idea/2016.3/settings-repository.html) plug-in is also an overkill for such a simple task.

Instead, [configure IntelliJ IDEA](https://www.jetbrains.com/help/idea/2016.3/copying-code-style-settings.html#d2146094e76) to store the code style and [inspection profiles](https://www.jetbrains.com/help/idea/2016.3/customizing-profiles.html#d2142849e10) inside the project, then [share your project files](https://intellij-support.jetbrains.com/hc/articles/206544839) with the team.