# Mapping Mac keyboard shortcuts to Intellij IDEA running on Windows

Tags: java, windows, macos, intellij-idea

I have a situation wherein I have a Mac laptop and have to remotely connect to my office's Windows machine which has Intellij IDEA running on it. I want to use all my Mac + Intellij keyboard shortcuts on the Windows machine, how do I make this work?

Answer (score 0):

You can navigate to `File` -> `Manage IDE Settings` -> `Export Settings` on your Mac and send `.zip` file to Windows machine. On Windows machine you need to navigate to `File` -> `Manage IDE Settings` -> `Import Settings` and select `.zip` file.

[How to save/export all the settings of IntelliJ IDEA?](https://stackoverflow.com/q/15863256/15777370)

Update:

Quote from

https://www.jetbrains.com/help/idea/sharing-your-ide-settings.html?keymap=secondary_macos#IDE_settings_sync

> Syntax
> ~/Library/Application Support/JetBrains//keymaps
> Example
> ~/Library/Application Support/JetBrains/IntelliJIdea2021.2/keymaps
> By default, this directory contains only the default keymaps. When you modify one of them, IntelliJ IDEA actually creates a child keymap file that contains only the differences relative to the parent keymap. For example, if you modified the default Windows keymap, your custom keymap will be its child. The file will contain only the shortcuts that you added or modified, while all other shortcuts of your custom keymap will be the same as the default Windows keymap.
>
> You can share your custom keymaps with team members or between your
> IDE instances. Copy the corresponding keymap file and put it in the
> keymaps directory on another IntelliJ IDEA installation. Then select
> the copied keymap on the Keymap settings page.

Comment: This does not work. The export did not create a `.jks` file but created a `settings.zip` file and on importing this file I did not see any changes with respect to the keyboard shortcuts.

Comment: I mixed up file extensions. `.jks` should not be created. Did you check `Key Maps` checkbox on export phase.

Comment: Everything in the list was already prechecked but I did not see `KeyMaps` checkbox in the list.

Comment: It's strange. Check this link https://www.jetbrains.com/help/idea/sharing-your-ide-settings.html?keymap=secondary_macos#IDE_settings_sync. There are a lot of ways to share settings.

Comment: This looks like a bug in Intellij IDEA - https://youtrack.jetbrains.com/issue/IDEA-181599?_ga=2.170722531.2102779982.1627805978-396804192.1624541157

Comment: Doesn't work, no change after importing.