# How do you export Settings->Editor->Inspections->Java->Declaration redundancy->Unused declaration->Entry Points->Annotations

Tags: java, intellij-idea

How do you export Settings->Editor->Inspections->Java->Declaration redundancy->Unused declaration->Entry Points->Annotations and similar settings?

For example, I have configured Spring's @Value and @Autowired annotations to be implicitly written to get rid of a lot of warnings generated by the IDE. I have a bunch of similar best practice configurations I want to share with developers on the team.

I have tried the suggested approach in [How to save/export all the settings of IntelliJ IDEA?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/15863256/how-to-save-export-all-the-settings-of-intellij-idea) but the exported zip does not contain my setting anywhere:

```
unzip settings.zip
grep -r -i autowire .
<empty result>
```

At the top of introspection I see I can export the Default IDE profile. The exported xml file also does not contain my annotations:

```
cat Default.xml
<profile version="1.0">
  <option name="myName" value="Default" />
</profile>
```

Comment: Do you use IDE global inspection profile or a project profile? If the latter, it will be stored in `.idea` directory and you should share it via the version control, see https://intellij-support.jetbrains.com/hc/en-us/articles/206544839.

Comment: We don't use .idea directory. However, if that's the only way we might have to migrate to that.

Comment: At the top of introspection I see I can export the Default IDE profile. The xml file also does not contain my annotations. Let me add that to the question.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Project inspection profiles are stored in `.idea/inspectionProfiles` directory and you can [share it via the version control](https://intellij-support.jetbrains.com/hc/en-us/articles/206544839).

You can also make it an IDE global profile that will be stored in the [IDE configuration directory](https://intellij-support.jetbrains.com/hc/en-us/articles/206544519), `inspections` subdirectory. One can use [read-only settings repository](https://www.jetbrains.com/help/idea/sharing-your-ide-settings.html#share-more-settings-through-read-only-repo) to share it with the team.

There is a [known bug](https://youtrack.jetbrains.com/issue/IDEA-84055) with exporting the inspection entry points.

Comment: I will experiment with the share it via version control.

Comment: I think that bug was the root cause. Thank you.